# Subversion "Replacing" Action

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

1. I create a branch,
2. Then I add a new folder and a new file in that folder (i.e. branch),
3. Then I preform an `svn add` and `svn commit`.

Then I do `svn merge` back into my trunk. When I then `svn commit` to my trunk the New folder gets "Added" but the file inside the folder get the "Replacing" action.

**Why do I get a Replace status on this file?**

Comment: Did you have file with the same name in your trunk before the merge?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/) **replaced** status means:

> The original item has been deleted and a new item with the same name
>   replaces it.

So obviously you should double-check actions you've performed. Do you have older revisions with the same folder and files (I mean their names)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any folders/files in your local copy that were deleted (locally) and not committed?
If you had a folder/file in your trunk that was deleted locally, that deletion must be committed to the repository.

Your situation sounds like you might not have a concurrent local copy.  For example, you might have deleted a folder/file in your local copy and not committed it.  Then, when you attempt to merge a branch with your local copy, the locally deleted folder/file (which was marked for deletion, but not committed) is being replaced by the branch's folder of the same name.  Since the folder/file deletion was not committed previously, the official state becomes "replaced".

Comment: The thing is there is no deleting happening. I am simply adding\comitting a new folder and file to my branch and then merging\comitting back into trunk. The folder and file has never existed in the trunk or branch before?